# Change an entire line in Vim

Tags: normal-mode

Is there a way to delete a full line and start with an insert? Normally I would do:

- `0` (go to start of line)
- `C` (delete to end of line and start insert)

But is there a command to do the above without having to first enter the `0`? Normally it's something like `ciw` or so to delete the 'wrapping' stuff (in this case the wrap is the line break).

The best I've gotten so far is now:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> (go to visual line mode)
- <kbd>c</kbd> (change at the start)

Comment: There's always dd shift-o

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the same way that `yy` copies the current line and `dd` deletes it, you can use `cc` to change it (i. e. yank it, delete it and enter insert mode). `S` is a synonym for `cc`.

Answer (score 14):

`cc` does what you want, I think?

From `:help cc`:

```
["x]cc      Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start
            insert |linewise|.  If 'autoindent' is on, preserve
            the indent of the first line.
```

Answer (score 9):

Three ways:

- `S` *[an abbreviation for `cc`]*
- `Vs` *[line-wise selection, then substitute]*
- `C` *[assuming the cursor is at the start of the line]*

plus various ways to visually select all the text on the line followed by one of `s` or `c`.

Note that you can replace multiple lines using `V`, by moving the cursor down or using `%` to select a block, then `s`.

Comment: thanks, what does small `s` do in `Vs` ? `V` would put it into visual line-mode, and then `s` ?

Comment: ```s``` is I think short for "substitute" - it changes whatever is selected (without a selection it's equivalent to ```cl``` i.e. change one character).